# Normalizing Flow Penalization

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, regularization, normalizing-flow

I am looking to train a normalizing flow, specifically a Masked Autoregressive Flow model. However, this model leads to high variance on lower dimensional, less complex data. I am using a neural network to parameterize the scale and shift components of the MAF. I think we need to smooth the loss surface, i.e., the log likelihood of the normalizing flow. Is there any literature outlining good ideas or what would be a good starting point?

Comment: You could check out [Huang 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00779) to compare what they did to what you want to do.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem like they penalize their loss though. Seems like standard ELBO VI